# How to store the result of a command to a variable in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm tryng to make a .bat file to add blank lines to a text file, based on the amount of lines that match a condition. This is what a have:

```
@echo
SET /a maxLineas = 50
SET cantLineasDetalle="type texto.txt | find /i /c "D01" "
SET /a cantLineasAgregar = %maxLineas% - %cantLineasDetalle%

:loop
echo. >> texto.txt
set /a cantLineasAgregar-=1
if %cantLineasAgregar% GTR 0 goto loop
```

The trouble is that var "cantLineasDetalle" isn't storing the value that I want it to do.

**How do I asign the result of the execution of 'type texto.txt | find /i /c "D01"' to a variable?**

Thanks in advance,
Esteban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the previous answer indicated, you use a FOR /F loop to store the results of a command into a variable.

`find "search" <file` can be significantly more efficient than `type file | find "search"` if the file is large.

When executed within a FOR /F IN() clause, all special characters must be either quoted or escaped. In your case the pipe will need to be escaped, or if you take my suggestion, the < will need to be escaped.

`echo. >>file` will append a line with a space to the file. Also, it is safer to use `echo(` instead of `echo.`, but you will probably never run into a problem with echo. To get a blank line without a space use `echo(>>file`

When using SET /A to do math, you can refer to variables directly without enclosing them in percents. It also works with the percents.

Lastly, it is much more efficient to append the lines within a FOR /L loop instead of using a GOTO loop.

```
@echo off
set /a maxLineas=50
for /f %%N in('find /i /c:"D01" ^<texto.txt') do set /a cantLineasDetalle=%%N
set /a cantLineasAgregar=maxLineas-cantLineasDetalle
for /l %%N in (1 1 %cantLineasAgregar%) do echo(>>texto.txt
```

The entire script could be compressed to the following (maxLineas is now 0 based)

```
@echo off
set /a maxLineas=50-1
for /f %%N in('find /i /c:"D01" ^<texto.txt') do for /l %%I in (%%N 1 %maxLineas%) do echo(>>texto.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. Just a few minutes before you respond I have found the answer playing with the console. That's what I've done: "for /f "tokens=3" %%G in ('find /i /c "D01" C:\texto.txt') do SET cantLineasDetalle=%%G" But I will use your recomendations to modify my code. I really apreciate your answer. Thanks, again.

Comment: @t3b4n - FIND is quirky: `FIND "search" file` is different than `FIND "search" <file`. The first generates 2 lines: file name followed by count. The second only generates the count. You probably want the second form.

Answer (score 0):

for /f %%i in ('type texto.txt | find /i /c "D01"') do SET cantLineasDetalle = %%i

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. It shows an error: "| not expected". I have replaced the fourth line of my code with yours to obtain that result.

Comment: The problem is `|` must be escaped within the IN() clause

Comment: My Windows-Fu has become quite rusty - long time since I polished it.